# How to store number of clicks/choices in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to make ‘Would You Rather’ app.

This basically involves two options that the user picks (e.g. Chocolate or Vanilla).

[image]

I want to be able to store the amount of times people chose each option.

I can only really think of one way of doing this:

Having each option as it’s own row in a database, and incrementing this each time the user picks it.

However, surely this would require making a request every time the user answers a question, and therefore handling (depending on the number of users) thousands of requests a minute? And wouldn’t there be an issue with two people trying to update the value at once?

I’m not sure how the best way to go about doing this is.

Comment: Will it be able to handle possibly dozens of requests a second? And is it bad practice to have the user performs that quantity of requests (could be one every ~5 seconds)

Comment: You're really asking about scalability now, which is something different than design.

Comment: I would store each user vote individually, only aggregating when querying or -- if necessary -- using a trigger to aggregate the values as the votes come in.

Comment: I would second @GordonLinoff - store individual votes along with other tracking meta-data (ip etc) so that you can aggregate as needed and also allow you to perform voting analysis in greater detail if required.

Comment: Do you mean store each vote as a separate row, and as an individual request?

Comment: @user2397282 . . . Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Does it matter that 59.00% + 42.000% = 101% !?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of programming language you are using so I will give a generalized answer.
If you want to save roundtrip from database one solution would be to create a temp file with votes for your options. This file can be update when user selects an option. To put these values in database you can create an background job which will collect data and store it in database in scheduled manner this will have a downside of not having current data in database but I think this will outweigh the benefits.

Comment: Ahh yes, I did think about this idea. I think I'm mostly worried about how well the database will handle the requests, and whether the app's performance will degrade when making a request each time. I guess it's a good trade off to buffer the votes, I just didn't know if that's what is normal practice for these applications.

Comment: I think when designing a database in these kind of scenario question to be asked is do you need current data or if slightly older data will work or have no impact. If yes then buffering data or manipulate it with background job and then putting it in database is a good choice.

Comment: I think you're right, it's not vital that data is 100% up-to-date

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a table which holds individual votes. It can have three columns, ID, IP address/username (or another identifying bit of information to stop duplicate votes) and what they voted for.

Whenever you want to calculate the current votes you can just do the count query while filtering out duplicate IP addresses/usernames.

If you are worried about database scalabilty it may be worthwhile looking into buffering the inserts into the database. For example storing the votes every 20 seconds or so and doing a batch insert.